# Change package name and make two directory to single in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to rename my package name from `com.codecanyon.advanceclassified` to `com.myapp`. As I have searched here and the web for an solution but every tutorial is saying about renaming single but it will not work for me because my app was already there in the Play Store with the package name of `com.myapp`.

I am using Android Studio version 3.0.1.

Below I have added the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Just follow the steps of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29092698/3669559

By the way, you cannot upload different app to Play Store with the existing package name, you can only update the existing one with using the same package name.

Comment: Hi,  it seems it was only helping to rename the folder but from com.codecanyon.advanceclassified to com.myapp.advanceclassified buy I need the app id to be com.myapp did you have any idea how to do it as my previous app was in the name of com.myapp

Comment: Your application id is placed in your gradle file as you see in picture above. Change it after renaming packages, your app id will be changed.

Comment: See updated answer dude.

Answer (score 0):

1. Manifest package name and application id are two different things. Don't be confused because they are same when project is created.
2. You can change the manifest package name any time after even uploaded on playstore.(**Only manifest package name**). Because it is related to your java classes.
3. Application id is created by gradle. Apk will have the application id finally which you have written in gradle.

So you can't change your gradle application id but you can change manifest package name when you have released build on playstore.

You can change package name `com.codecanyon.advanceclassified` to `com.myapp` but don't change applicationId."

**Update:**

After understanding your senario, you can do this.

- You need not to change package name of java classes in manifest.
- You **just change application Id as same as your previous app on playstore**. and you are good to go. :)

Comment: Let me know if you need help in changing package name.

Comment: Hi, I got your point buy is there any way to rename the application id as my app was already there in the play store with the name of com.myapp
I tried the method of  Oğuzhan Döngül  as it seems it was only helping to rename the folder but from com.codecanyon.advanceclassified to com.myapp.advanceclassified buy I need the app id to be com.myapp

Comment: Never do this mistake to change application Id if your app is already on playstore. It is like a unique name, if  you change package name then it will become another app.

Comment: Why you need to change application Id ?

Comment: As my app in the google playstore with the name of com.myapp if I want to upload an update to play store the package name to be same as previous (com.myapp)

Comment: Are you confused with update process of playstore, there will be no change in package name, just version code and version name will be changed.

Comment: khemraj, I know that see the my app was uploaded to the play store with the app ID com.myapp. As my computer got effected of wanny cry I lost the files and i need to use the old backup as my old backup have another name in the app id that was com.codecanyon.advanceclassified so now i have made some changes in the layout and tried to upload the app as update it was saying the app id to same as previous com.myapp Version also need to change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170100/discussion-between-parvathy-nair-and-khemraj).